# Differential forms on a product of space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $X,Y$ be (smooth, say) spaces. Is it true that $$\Omega^r_{X\times Y}=\bigoplus_{i+j=r}\Omega^i_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}}\Omega^j_Y\,\,?$$

This seems rather strong in general, but I am certain that this is true when $Y=|\Delta_p|$ is the smooth $p$-simplex. However, I cannot find either a proof of the general statement or a proof of this specific case.
(It's annoyingly tricky to find references about forms on product spaces, since the moment you have the keywords 'product' and 'forms' you invariably find only references for products of forms.)

Comment: Manifolds have partitions of unity so this reduces to the local calculation on $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m$, in which case it more or less follows from the definition of an r-form.

Comment: Be careful. This decomposition is only local, not global. Are you intending this as a global sections statement or as a sheaf statement?

Comment: But Mike's point is right: If you make sure to take a (finite) sum of wedge products of (pullbacks of) $i$-forms on $X$ with $(r-i)$-forms on $Y$ then it will work. As Mike suggested, bump functions allow you to localize and then add up.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was hoping to have this statement locally, just for sections over an open set

Comment: @Tim: Just work in a small enough open set $U\times V$ so that you have local coordinates on $U\subset X$ and local coordinates on $V\subset Y$, and then it'll fall out immediately.